# Getting Low Memory Logs/Reports on iOS Programmatically

Tags: ios, memory

I am currently using PLCrashReporter to get the crash reports on ios device programmatically. According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html , http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs Memory logs are different than crash logs. How can I get this memory logs programmatically ? Are there any libraries available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Instruments to determine why the memory is being exhausted. Use the Analyzer to check your code. Use Instruments Leaks tool.

Use instruments to check for leaks and memory loss due to retained but not leaked memory. The latter is unused memory that is still pointed to. Use Mark Generation (Heapshot) in the Allocations instrument on Instruments.

For HowTo use Heapshot to find memory creap, see: [bbum blog](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/)

Basically the method is to run Instruments allocate tool, take a heapshot, run an iteration of your code and take another heapshot repeating 3 or 4 times. This will indicate memory that is allocated and not released during the iterations.

To figure out the results disclose to see the individual allocations.

If you need to see where retains, releases and autoreleases occur for an object use instruments:

Run in instruments, in Allocations set "Record reference counts" on (For Xcode 5 and lower you have to stop recording to set the option). Cause the app to run, stop recording, drill down and you will be able to see where all retains, releases and autoreleases occurred.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer the original question? The question was how to retrieve this iOS generated "memory logs" (as https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html pointed out that this report is created, but no instruction on how to get it), not how to debug memory issues in general.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to plug in the device to Xcode. Go to Window > Devices and Simulators, select your device, click "View Device logs" button. Low memory logs will be in there under process "Unknown" and type "Unknown".

See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1747/_index.html under "Getting Crash Logs and Console Output From a Device Using Xcode" section.